# Use Python lambda expression to match two patterns and generate a map

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple lines similar to the below string and I want to extract request and Reason from all the lines as a pair.

```
s = 'Service: demo caused request=request1 to emit Fault=1 with Reason= HTTP 500 Internal Server Error'


logline_regex = r'.* Service: (?P<entity>\w+) caused request =(?P<request_id>.*) to' \
                        + '\s*emit Fault=' + str(fault_value) + \
                        '\s*with Reason=(?P<failure_reason>.*)'
map_event_to_match = map(lambda event: re.match(logline_regex, event), events)
match_filter = filter(lambda match: match and 'request_id' in match.groupdict(), map_event_to_match)
```

I want to extract request_id and failure_reason from all the log lines in a pair. I know I can extract single entity something similar to

```
match_to_is = map(lambda match: match.groupdict()['request_id'],
                            match_filter))
```

but I want to extract both request_id and failure_reason as a pair.

Looking for possible ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the lambda return a tuple for every match.
Example below (not using your code because it has some undefined variables).

```py
In []: events = ['A=1, B=2', 'A=3, B=4']

In []: pattern = 'A=(?P<a>\\d), B=(?P<b>\\d)'

In []: map_event_to_match = map(lambda event: re.match(pattern, event), events)

In []: list(map(lambda match: (match.groupdict()["a"], match.groupdict()["b"]), map_event_to_match))
Out[]: [('1', '2'), ('3', '4')]
```